# Do I misunderstand the continue statement?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, continue

I'm trying to test smileys in a list. Here's the exercise:

Given an array (arr) as an argument complete the function countSmileys that should return the total number of smiling faces.

Rules for a smiling face:

- Each smiley face must contain a valid pair of eyes. Eyes can be marked as : or ;
- A smiley face can have a nose but it does not have to. Valid characters for a nose are - or ~
- Every smiling face must have a smiling mouth that should be marked with either ) or D.

No additional characters are allowed except for those mentioned.

Valid smiley face examples:
:) :D ;-D :~)
Invalid smiley faces:
;( :> :} :]**

The value returned by my code is always either 0, or the length of the whole list. It's as if my booleans eye, nose, mouth never get reassigned the value of False at the beginning of my for loop.

What's going on?

Here's my program:

```py
def count_smileys(arr):

    count = 0
    for smile in arr:
        eye = False
        nose = False
        mouth = False
        if len(smile) == 2:
            if smile[0] == ":" or ";":
                eye = True
            else:
                continue
            if smile[1] == ")" or "D":
                mouth = True
            else:
                continue
            if eye and mouth:
                count += 1
        if len(smile) == 3:
            if smile[0] == ":" or ";":
                eye = True
            else:
                continue
            if smile[1] == "-" or "~":
                nose = True
            else:
                continue
            if smile[2] == ")" or "D":
                mouth = True
            else:
                continue
            if eye and nose and mouth:
                count += 1
    return count

print(count_smileys([';]', ':[', ';*', ':$', ';-D']))
```

Comment: Hard to say if you misunderstand the `continue` statement since you haven't described what you think it does. As for "What's going on?", that's not really an answerable question. A lot of things are going on. What do you want to know? Listing expected input/output vs. actual input/output would be a good start if you're looking for clarification (or ask a more precise question if you have one).

Comment: The function, given the input at the end, should return a value of 1, because there is only one valid smiley.

What I think continue does, is stop the running the code in the for block, and run it over the next smiley in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are misunderstanding is the `or` statement.

When you write:

```
if smile[0] == ":" or ";":
```

The first expression tested is `smile[0] == ":"`. If that is `False` then the second expression is tested, which, in this case, is just `";"`.  You can see that this always evaluates to `True` by trying this in a Python shell:

```
>>> bool(";")
True
>>> bool(False or ";")
True
```

So your `or` statement should instead be:

```
if smile[0] == ":" or smile[0] == ";":
```

You've done this will all of your `or` statements, so you will need to fix those.